# I want to know the location of file added to blob storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob container at Azure blob storage and inside this container there are many directories. Again inside those directories there can be other directories. Now suppose if someone adds a blob to anywhere inside the container, I want the location and blob name. Please help me with your inputs.

I have tried basic blobtrigger azure function, but couldnot make it more.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use an Azure Event Grid eventing feature for azure storage account. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

Comment: You are supposed to get `path/filename` with `containerName/{name}` path setting, what location do you need, relative path under the container or complete url? Also, what language do you use?

Comment: I am using Java and whole path would be fine..!! I just want to locate the file inside these nested directories. 
My requirement is whenever new blobs are added to any of subdirectories I should be able to locate them.

Comment: @KunalTrivedi The sample java blob trigger has `path = "samples-workitems/{name}"` and `@BindingName("name") String name`, doesn't `name` give you the `dir../filename`?  could you elaborate `whole path`, in the format of `containerName/dir.../filename` or what?

Comment: @JerryLiu yes thats exactly I would need. containername/dir/filename whenever the file gets uploaded anywhere inside container (under subdirectories too)..!!

Comment: Okay so lemme once try this by blobtrigger weather it gives whole path or not..!!

Comment: @KunalTrivedi `name` doesn't provide container name, only `dir/filename`

Comment: @KunalTrivedi If the solution works for you, do you mind accepting it for others to refer?

Answer (score 2):

Have a try at code below. Metadata `name` offers blobName, which includes directories and its filename. `BlobTrigger` offers whole path as you wish, i.e. containerName/blobName.

```
@FunctionName("BlobTriggerJava")
@StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
public void run(
    @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "containerName/{name}", dataType = "binary") byte[] content,
    @BindingName("name") String name, @BindingName("BlobTrigger") String wholePath, 
    final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob. Name: " + name);
    context.getLogger().info("Whole path: " + wholePath);
}
```